# How to subclass UIApplication in Monotouch?

Tags: c#, ios, uikit, xamarin.ios, uiapplication

**EDIT:**

A couple of years later, things are easier. It is now possible to omit the
`Register()` attributes, both on the application and the app delegate and instead use:

`UIApplication.Main(args, typeof(CustomApp), typeof(CustomAppDelegate));`

---

In order to be able to override UIApplication.SendEvent() I want to subclass UIApplication:

```
public class UIApplicationMain : UIApplication
{
    public UIApplicationMain () : base()
    {
    }

    public override void SendEvent (UIEvent uievent)
    {
        base.SendEvent (uievent);
    }
}
```

In the main.cs I use this code:

```
public class Application
{
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        UIApplication.Main (args, "UIApplicationMain", "AppDelegateBase");
    }
}
```

But it fails with:

> ```
> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
> ```
>
> NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Unable to instantiate the
>   UIApplication subclass instance. No class named UIApplicationMain is
>   loaded.

So I'm missing some attributes I guess. But what and where?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add a **[Register]** attribute to your new type, like:

```
 [Register ("UIApplicationMain")]
 public class UIApplicationMain : UIApplication {
    ...
```

That will allow the native side to instantiate the right type when Main gets executed.

Comment: Good god! It can be so easy sometimes!

Comment: `UIApplication.Main(args, "UIApplicationMain", "AppDelegate");`is also needed.